# neo4j Dynamic Relationship Types, not with enums

Tags: java, enums, neo4j

How would I take the string "KNOWS" and use it as a Relationship type instead of using an enum  RelTypes.KNOWS ... I need to dynamically add relationship instead of using only the 2 enums RelTypes.KNOWS and RelTypes.IS_FRIENDS_WITH

```
// START SNIPPET: createReltype
private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
{
    KNOWS,
    IS_FRIENDS_WITH
}
// END SNIPPET: createReltype

public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    // START SNIPPET: startDb
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase( DB_PATH );
    registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
    // END SNIPPET: startDb

    // START SNIPPET: operationsInATransaction
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    try
    {
        Node john = graphDb.createNode();
        john.setProperty("name", "John" );
        Node george = graphDb.createNode();
        george.setProperty("name", "George" );

        firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS );

        tx.success();
    }
    finally
    {
        tx.finish();
    }
    // END SNIPPET: removingData

    System.out.println( "Shutting down database ..." );
    // START SNIPPET: shutdownServer
    graphDb.shutdown();
    // END SNIPPET: shutdownServer
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating relationship types dynamically from a string is exactly what [`org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicRelationshipType`](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.3/org/neo4j/graphdb/DynamicRelationshipType.html) exists for.